# C# foreach behavior with derived classes?

Tags: c#

Right now I have a relatively simple class setup:

```
class A{
//stuff
}
class B:A{
//more stuff
}
public List<A> ListOfObjects;
```

What would happen if I do

```
foreach(B i in ListOfObjects)
```

would I get only objects of type B? Would it apply some OO magic and convert all As to Bs? Would this even work?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If the list had `A`'s in it (or other things that aren't `B` or subclasses of `B`), then it would simply break with an invalid-cast. You probably want:

```
foreach(B i in ListOfObjects.OfType<B>()) {...}
```

in .NET 3.5. (I'm assuming that the list itself will be non-null, btw)

Answer (score 7):

I personally use `var` as the loop variable in `foreach` under all circumstances, to avoid any possibility of an invalid runtime cast. That way, the type of the loop variable will be the static type of the collection's items; if you want something else, use `OfType` to perform a safe filtering cast.

[Some more explanation here.](http://smellegantcode.wordpress.com/2009/08/05/how-var-fixes-a-type-hole-in-c/)

Answer (score 3):

foreach lists *all* objects in the collection. If the runtime type of an item is not compatible to the type of the iterator variable (in your case i of type B) a TypeCasException is thrown.

Instead you can do this:

```
foreach(A i in ListOfObjects)
{
   B b = i as B
   if (b!=null) ..
}
```

Or you can filter the list before iterating it. The simplest solution will be a linq query.